# I'd like to create a program that returns basic AzureAD information without tying it to one tenant

Tags: c#, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm not a C# programmer so forgive the ignorance, but I'm trying to create a program that will use the Graph API to do simple AzureAD commands, such as listing users, groups, etc. All articles that I've read on how to do this says the app first needs to be registered within AzureAD in order to do this, but I'd like this program to not be tied to that tenant. It'd prefer to just have a user authenticate to their tenant and use that access token to access Azure instead. I'd love any resources or where to begin. I tried to follow this article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/write-your-first-program-using-microsoft-graph-sdk/ but it didn't work.

Comment: This is not possible. You have to register your app if you are going to use Graph API. Please follow the guidelines and the best practices recommended

Comment: You do not need to register an app to a tenant. I have Python examples that use the Graph API and they are not registered. However, you will need to know the Tenant ID to authenticate. Then you can list users, etc. The example that you posted is a good example. Why not learn and figure out what is wrong? If you are not experienced with c# and you are not experienced with Azure AD, you have a big hill to climb.

Comment: @JohnHanley my concern is if this is an open source program, I don't want my specific tenant tied to it. I'm 100% fine with it prompting for login similar to how the `az` module works in PS and getting a token that way.

Comment: @Rooskyyy If you want to know Azure AD information, the tenant must be provided. If not, how does the application know which AzureAD information you want to get?

Comment: @TonyJu Perhaps I'm thinking about it in the wrong way. My assumption would be the tenant is selected by the UI that prompts the user for authentication. This is done in PS via `az login` and the token is then stored in ~/.azure. Is this not possible in C#?

Comment: @Rooskyyy It is possible, but you need to implement it yourself. You can list the tenants https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list

Comment: @Rooskyyy Do you know multi tenant? You can configure your application to accept sign-ins from any Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant. If tenantA user sign-in, he will be able to get tenantA information, if tenantB user sign-in, he will be able to get tenantB information.

Comment: @TonyJu - Thank you for the link. I was looking for that API.

Comment: @Rooskyyy - I will release an article using the Azure Tenants - List API with Python and C# source code. I will probably work on that this weekend. My personal website is https://www.jhanley.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach is to register the app in your tenant as a multi-tenant app.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps

This will allow the users to login with their tenant. 
Your app can define the permissions it requires, which the other tenant users must consent to.

Comment: Thank you. Is it a security risk at all to have my tenant's client ID hardcoded?

Comment: The client id is public. It is needed in the authentication redirect and is thus visible to the user.

Comment: @Rooskyyy The Tenant ID can be determined from your domain name. There is a website that shows this. If I can locate the site again, I will update my comment. Therefore, I am assuming that the Tenant ID is not a secret. Note: this ability might be related to Office 365 and not Azure AD.

Comment: Yes the tenant id is not a secret either. You can go to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/domain.com/.well-known/openid-configuration` to see the id. Replace domain.com with any domain name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know Azure AD information, the tenant must be provided.

You can get the tenants for your account by calling

```
GET https://management.azure.com/tenants?api-version=2019-06-01
```

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list